# Get(groot) not working in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using a matlab toolbox to analyze skin conductance data (http://pspm.sourceforge.net/). This is the only extra toolbox that I added to my matlab path.

My analysis runs well until I reach an error inside one of the toolbox's functions:

```
Undefined function or variable 'groot'.
```

The line causing the problem is:

```
corder = get(groot, 'defaultAxesColorOrder');
```

Now, get(groot) is a matlab method: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/groot.html and is not a function that needs to be defined.

To check whether I'm shadowing the proper get function, I went into debug mode and just before that line is executed, I checked:

```
K>> which get
built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/toolbox/matlab/graphics/get)
```

As far as I understand the problem is not in the toolbox but in matlab itself (I'm using Matlab R2012a), which is why I post on SO and not in their bug report. On the other hand I have the same problem in two different computers. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: no problem on my computer. You get the same problem if you try to save the groot variable before ? grootvar = groot ?

Comment: Type this and report the output please.  `r = groot`

Comment: Does `get(0)` work? I think old Matlab versions don't have `groot`; but the root graphics object has handle `0`.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012a/search.html?qdoc=groot&pg=desktop&submitsearch=Search   This is the 2012a documentation.  It couldn't find `groot`.  Update Matlab.

Comment: get(gcf, 'defaultAxesColorOrder') isn't similar ?

Comment: @Matt, `r=groot` outputs the same error message: Undefined function or variable. Thanks for your answer, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groot` appears to be part of Matlab's updated graphics system that came out in 2014b.  Instead access the figure you want to modify directly.

```
fh = figure;
corder = get(fh, 'defaultAxesColorOrder');
```

Comment: I think that you can directly write: get(gcf, 'defaultAxesColorOrder');

Comment: by the way, get(gcf, 'defaultAxesColorOrder'); and get(groot, 'defaultAxesColorOrder'); give differents results if you don't have matlab 2015

Comment: @obchardon It's true `get(gcf....` will work but what if the point is to handle multiple figures?  Since I don't know the rest of what's going on returning the figure handle as `fh` means I can always easily get to it.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I was confused and read that groot had been introduced before R2006, but that applies to get, not to groot.